# Windows.Devices.Radios are not working in the x86 platform

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, desktop-application

My target is to verify that the device has Bluetooth, and if it has one, then verify that the Bluetooth is turned on or off. For that purpose, I am using the below code snippet.

```
public async Task<bool> GetBluetoothStatusAsync()
{
    var allRadio = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
    if (allRadio == null) return false;
    var bluetoothRadio = allRadio.FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Kind == RadioKind.Bluetooth);
    return bluetoothRadio != null && bluetoothRadio.State == RadioState.On;
}
```

It's not working when called from a desktop Win32 app.
Windows.Devices.Radios are working fine if the targeted platform is set to x64, but for the x86, it's not working. From the [windows git issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/47), it looks like this is a known issue, and it's not solved yet. Is there any workaround available for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, but just in case anyone else is looking:

From the Windows doc: When this method is called from a desktop application (Win32), it will retrieve radio instances only when the application is natively compiled for the target architecture (in other words, when the application matches the computer architecture; so ***an x86 application running on an x64 architecture computer won't see any radio instances***).